# Boostrap ish CSS not working as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I had to develop a website with columns but I was not allowed to use bootstrap. So I decided to borrow some stuff from their grid to help me.

I created my code like this:

```
.container {
    width: 970px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.container:before, .container:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.container:after {
    clear: both;
}

.container .row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.container .row:before, .container .row:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.container .row:after {
    clear: both;
}

.container .row .col-1, .container .row .col-2, .container .row .col-3, .container .row .col-4, .container .row .col-5, .container .row .col-6, .container .row .col-7, .container .row .col-8, .container .row .col-9, .container .row .col-10, .container .row .col-11, .container .row .col-12 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    /*padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;*/
}

.container .row .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.container .row .col-11 {
    width: 91.66667%;
}

.container .row .col-10 {
    width: 83.33333%;
}

.container .row .col-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.container .row .col-8 {
    width: 66.66667%;
}

.container .row .col-7 {
    width: 58.33333%;
}

.container .row .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.container .row .col-5 {
    width: 41.66667%;
}

.container .row .col-4 {
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.container .row .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.container .row .col-2 {
    width: 16.66667%;
}

.container .row .col-1 {
    width: 8.33333%;
}
```

The problem is that this has no padding between columns as it does on bootstrap. If I try to add the padding my columns wrap onto two lines.
Without the padding, it works fine.

I created a [jsfiddle here to show without padding](http://jsfiddle.net/987u646s/)

now with -margin on the row I expected to be able to add padding on the columns and it work, but [as you can see from this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/987u646s/1/), it wraps onto two lines...

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above you are commenting out the padding in your columns. You will also need to add box-sizing to your grid. Easiest way...

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I had figured this out :D by examining another site and going through using the developer tools and deselecting css rules, but thanks, this will help someone else I hope

Answer (score 1):

This is just the way how bootstrap works. Each col-6 takes 50% width of container, even if you add 1px padding, it will shows like two rows because the width of each col-6 is 50%+1px, and (50%+1px)times two > 100%(the width of container). You can do like

`<div class="col-5 yellow">`

`<div class="col-2">`

`<div class="col-5 green">`

This will give you a col-2 "padding" between column. Or you can do nested div like

`<div class="col-6">`

`<div class="padding yellow">`

`<p>haha</p>`

`</div>`

`</div>`
And css should be like 
`.padding{margin:0 10px;}`

Answer (score 0):

your `div` is getting very large width try to decrease it here is code of width

```
.container .row .col-6 {
  width: 50%;// try to decrease it less then 40%
  }
```